# STM32 C : atoi converts part of string which is not an argument

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, atoi

I have parsed some date and time from GPS receiver. And need to convert them from string to `int`:

```
char year[4] = "2014";
char month[2] = "01";
char day[2] = "24";
char hour[2] ="12";
char minute[2] = "58";
char second[2] = "39";

GPS_current_year = atoi(year);
GPS_current_month = atoi(month);
GPS_current_day = atoi(day);
GPS_current_hour = atoi(hour);
GPS_current_minute = atoi(minute);
GPS_current_second = atoi(second);
```

After executing these the results are:

[image]

Somehow part of minutes string is converted when converting hour string. Same with minutes and seconds.

The strings are placed side by side in the memory.

If I change the sequence of defining strings then seconds may be added to years etc.

Questions:

- What may cause this error?
- Is there any way to avoid this error with using `atoi`?

I know that I can convert using a loop one `char` at a time. Just trying to find why is it not working.

Comment: If those arrays are supposed to be string, they are to small as you forget the special string terminator character. Generally, for strings, you don't need to specify a size, and if you do they must be at least one character larger than the length of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the missing quotes around the strings your char array's size should be defined to hold one more char the EOS (end of string a binary zero).

Since the memory representation would be e.g. "2014\0"

```
char year[4+1] = "2014";
```

Comment: THIS!!! Thank You a lot. 
defining was only for example, its not defined that way in original code. Will fix my post in few seconds.

Comment: Better: Just omit the size and let the compiler figure it out: `char year[] = "2014"` -- or, if you don't need to modify it, `const char *year = "2014";`

Answer (score 3):

Suggest not trying to define the string size as 4 **or** 5.
Let the compiler determine the string size.

```
char year[] = "2014";
```

In this case, the compiler will make `year` with a size of 5 initialized with `'2'`, `'0'`, `'1'`, `'4'`, `'\0'`.

OP's defining the size as 4 resulted in a size of 4-char array without a terminating `'\0'`, which not being a string, create problems with `atoi(year)`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quotes in the strings:

```
char year[4] = "2014";
```

Comment: That would cause a compile-time error, not the run-time symptom the OP describes. The question has been updated. But `char year[4] = "2014";` doesn't create a string because there's no room for the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi()` converts string to integer. But you are giving non string values to your string variables. Change your code to

```
char year[5] = "2014";
char month[3] = "01";
char day[3] = "24";
char hour[3] ="12";
char minute[3] = "58";
char second[3] = "39";
```

Comment: That would cause a compile-time error, not the run-time symptom the OP describes. The question has been updated. But `char year[4] = "2014";` doesn't create a string because there's no room for the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Why bother specifying the sizes of the arrays rather than letting the compiler figure it out? `char year[] = "2014";`